# Can you place the gpu on a metal surface?

Tags: gpu

The metal surface would be aluminum and it is the "theoretical" pc case that is has the above mentioned gpu plugged in to it an running, basically it is a half\open case with the gpu on top.
Making the case completely out of plexi, would that be a good idea.

Comment: What are you trying to do? The GPU plugs into the main board socket on one side and will likely be connected to a heat sink on the other side via thermal compound.

Answer (score 2):

A heatsink is a metal surface, so the back of a GPU can definately be in contact with a metal surface.

You want to keep metal away from any parts that carry electricity.

If you are using the case as the heatsink for the GPU ensure that the metal is thick enough that the GPU does not overheat.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. Even if you're lucky and don't get a short circuit from doing it, the aluminum is going to heat and damage your GPU in the short or long run.

Plexiglass is ok if it can tolerate some heat, check out the material specifications beforehand, this can vary dractically from one plexi to another.